# One round at a time round robin scheduling algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm hoping to run a program that helps me randomly generate one round of a round-robin schedule. That is, suppose I've already played 5 rounds, I want to generate the sixth (and only the sixth) round of games. We'll say there are 4 teams for the quick example. I want the algorithm to generate a home and away game for each team:

1 @ 3

2 @ 1

3 @ 4

4 @ 2

This is where I'm at for how I want my algorithm to look:

1. I have a list of teams (I actually have 12)
2. I want to try all schedule possibilities until I have a game for each team that works.

Right now I got:

Have a list of away teams and a list of home teams
For each away team:

1. Remove themselves
2. Remove opponents they've already played
3. Remove opponents already scheduled to host another team that round.
4. Pair them with a randomly selected remaining home team.

I'd like to do this in one while loop. But I'm having trouble with removing all the matches when one doesn't work. For example, suppose that the only two away teams to schedule are teams 11, and 12, with home teams 1 and 2 remaining. If both 11 and 12 have played team 1, then the schedule is no good and I need to start back with away team 1. How do I do that in line?

I'm stuck, but this is what it generally looks like right now so hopefully you can sort what I'm attempting.

```
def findNextMatchups(playedMatchups):
    scheduleGood=False
    tentativeSchedule=[]
    opponents=teams.copy()
    while not scheduleGood:
        for i in range(len(teams)):
            human=teams[i]
            availableOpps=findAvailableOpps(human,playedMatchups)
            opponent=chooseOpponent(availableOpps)
            if opponent==False:
                continue
            else:
                tentativeSchedule.append((human,opponent))
        scheduleGood=True
```

Help?

Comment: what will be your expected result?

Comment: The next weeks schedule. 12 games with each away team visiting a team they haven't played yet.

Comment: You're looking for a [maximum matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching#Algorithms_for_arbitrary_graphs) algorithm.

Comment: Ok, was able to resolve it. My findNextMatchups is just calling another functoin, which does the checks there. Nesting it in another function made it all clear somehow. Thanks for the point in the right direction!